# Custom Tables and Dashlets in Sugar CRM

Tags: module, sugarcrm

I have been tasked to create a custom Dashlet which displays graphs of marketing data that is imported into a custom table in SugarCRM. I have been trying to read up on the subject but most of what I find is confusing and doesn't address what I need:

A custom table that stores events.

A Dashlet which pulls info from the above custom table and related Account information from the foreign key (account_id) in the custom table.

Suggestions, resources, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the graphs you want to display, you may be able to use a custom report feature. You can create a dashlet based on a graphical report and display it on the home page.

1. create a custom report the utilizes the data you need from the custom module. Make sure you save it as your assigned to and team - also it MUST be a "summation" or "summation with details" report
2. pull up the "add sugar dashlets" on your homepage and locate the report you made in the "my reports" section at the bottom of your charts tab.
3. When you click on it it will load as a chart style dashlet.

Answer (score 2):

Install the zucker report module and generate the graphical report .